# Trying out OAuth2 via CURL - The grant type was not specified in the request

Tags: php, curl, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use CURL on my terminal to perform a OAuth client:

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=Barn Coop Farm&amp;client_secret=b9c186fff02a3c40ffbe336017370ced&amp;grant_type=client_credentials" http://coop.apps.knpuniversity.com/token
```

but I have this error below from the server:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The grant type was not specified in the request"}
```

But if I use PHP CURL:

```
$params = array();
$params['grant_type'] = 'client_credentials';
$params['client_id'] = 'Barn Coop Farm';
$params['client_secret'] = 'b9c186fff02a3c40ffbe336017370ced';

$url = 'http://coop.apps.knpuniversity.com/token';

$ch = curl_init();
$header = array ();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
echo $response;
```

I get the correct response:

```
{"access_token":"95d07fbb9964d567493c7517c25acde8a8b43ab6","expires_in":86400,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"eggs-collect"}
```

Any ideas why and what have I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your curl request you have your `&` as `&amp;` when separating the parameters.

Comment: so should i use & instead of &amp; ?

Comment: Yes, you separate params with an `&`. See the syntax [here](http://superuser.com/a/149335/148519).